# Selenium loop the buttonClick

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, web-crawler

I am trying to scrape all the bikes from this page:
https://www.reconpowerbikes.com/recon-bikes/
but it only has the names without price, lets say if i want to click the number and click the "Shop Now" button from this page and go to each page to get the current price, (the bikes is switching periodically). how can i do it by selenium

[image: pic1]

```
!apt-get update
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
!cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin
!pip install selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
#set up Chrome driver
options=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
#Define web driver as a Chrome driver
driver=webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=options)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

URL='https://www.reconpowerbikes.com/recon-bikes/'
driver.get(URL)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div/div[@class="blaze-pagination"]/button[@class=""]'))).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try beautiful soup to extract URLs from page source or java script. following is the javascript version.

```
result = driver.execute_script('''
allbikes=document.querySelectorAll(".blaze-slider__description") 
result=[]
for (var i = 0; i < allbikes.length; i++) {
    let bike=allbikes[i]
    let bike_url=bike.getElementsByClassName("blaze-slider__button")[0]
    //console.log(bike_url.getAttribute("href"))
  result.push(bike_url.getAttribute("href"))
}
return result
''')
for bike in result:
    print(bike)
    #for each bike URL, access the page and then get the price
```

Javascript: get all the slider divs, and then for each div, get the href attribute.